# Set coordination number cutoff in CP2K's D3 dispersion

Tags: cp2k, dispersion-correction

The D3 dispersion correction has 2 distance cutoff values. One for the calculation of coordination numbers, one for the energy contribution.
In other implementations, such as vasp and DFTB+ (tblite), the coordination number cutoff is set to around 20 Angstrom by default.

https://www.vasp.at/wiki/index.php/DFT-D3
https://dftbplus.org/documentation

However, in CP2K I am not able to find a way to set this parameter. The only thing that comes close is EPS_CN. The description reads:

> Cutoff value for coordination number function (DFT-D3 method)

which I find hard to interpret given a default value of 1e-6.
Neither Bohr nor angstrom make sense as units for this value.
Is it perhaps the threshold under which a neighboring atom does not contribute to the CN anymore?

https://manual.cp2k.org/trunk/CP2K_INPUT/FORCE_EVAL/DFT/XC/VDW_POTENTIAL/PAIR_POTENTIAL.html#CP2K_INPUT.FORCE_EVAL.DFT.XC.VDW_POTENTIAL.PAIR_POTENTIAL.EPS_CN

I am asking because I have tried out a few D3 implementations and they are all in agreement except the one in CP2K.
It is unclear to me whether I am actually using the same parameters as in these other versions, since I am not able to find the keywords.